# Unable to update attribute value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

The `Key` model has the following migration

```
class CreateKeys < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :keys do |t|
      t.string :value
      t.integer :alive_time
      t.integer :block_time

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Running the following does not update the `block_time` value:

```
@available_keys = Key.where(:block_time => 0)
@key = Key.find(@available_keys[0].id)
@key.update_attribute(:block_time, Time.now.to_i)
```

I tried some variants in the `rails console`:

**Running:** `Key.find(10).update_attributes({:block_time => Time.now.to_i})`
**Causes:** `UPDATE "keys" SET "value" = ?, "alive_time" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "keys"."id" = ?`

The SQL being run updates the `alive_time` but not the `block_time`

Why? How do I ensure correct behaviour?

---

**EDIT**
The `schema.rb` contents:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150708123716) do

  create_table "keys", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "value"
    t.integer  "alive_time"
    t.integer  "block_time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: How are you getting `@available_keys`?

Comment: @Pavan `@available_keys = Key.where(:block_time => 0)`

Comment: Provide your actual **schema.rb** file, please.

Comment: Very strange. Seems like `block_time` attribute is somehow redefined to `actual_time`. Is there any method in model that change default behaviour? Guess no but who knows...

Comment: @hedgesky I just checked -  `update_column` seems to be working correctly, `update_attribute` and `update_attributes` are both misbehaving

Comment: So DB is configured properly, looks like `block_time=` is redefined or so. Maybe there is any module or concern included into model that introduced wrong behaviour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82725/discussion-between-sinstein-and-hedgesky).

Comment: @Sinstein Did you ever figure this out? I seem to be running into the exact same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483809/rails-model-fails-to-save-cached-column-counts

Comment: @LannyBose I dont think I did and sadly I cannot recall why I had come across this issue :(